# Cancellation property holds in ideals in Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, integral-domain, dedekind-domain

Let $D$ be a Dedekind domain. Let $A,B,C$ be ideals of $D$ with $A\neq 0$ and $AB=AC$. Prove that $B=C$.

I know that every fractional ideal is invertible here but what will happen with any ideal in general!

Comment: I think that I have got it. We have to use the unique representation in terms of prime ideals. Please confirm!!

Comment: You could use this, but it also follows form the fact that all fractional ideals are invertible.